# Flutter: Framework not found BoringSSL-GRPC while building for IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I have been working on update for a Flutter app that uses `Firebase Firestore`, once I finished the updated and starting to build it for IOS, I got the following short error message which cause the build operation to fail:

```
Error (Xcode): Framework not found BoringSSL-GRPC
```

So what should I do to get over this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you are using `Firebase Firestore` in your app, then you case might be the same of mine.

In the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) of `Firebase Firestore` for Flutter, you will notice an **Optional** step that tells you to add a line in the `Podfile` to improve iOS & macOS build times by including the pre-compiled framework, like this one:

```
target 'Runner' do
  ...
  # This is the mentioned line
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
  ...
end
```

The solution for me was to ignore this optional step and remove this line from the `Podfile`. The build operation would take longer than before but it is better than a build failure.